# Потоки внутри порта

Tags: python, сокет

Возможно ли создать какие либо потоки внутри порта? Мне это нужно для Python socket, у меня есть 2 функции которые работают одновременно и слушают команды от клиента, проблема в том что команды могут смешиваться, например: функция1 получит команду, которая была отправлена функции2

Comment: Видимо, изобретать какой-то свой протокол и между сокетом и функциями ставить какую-то вспомогательную прослойку, которая будет распихивать данные из сокета по правильным функциям

Comment: А нет более простого решения?

Comment: делайте команды уникальными для функций. обозначайте идентификаторами, например. если он есть, то первая функция работает, а вторая - нет. и наоборот. вы как-то слишком усложняете все

Comment: Мне нужно чтоб обе эти функции работали 24/7